# Passar o return (inteiro) de um método do Controller para a View

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, razor

Tenho este método num *controller*:

```
int GetSpot()
{
    List<CompanyDetail> topCompanies = GetTopCompanies();
    CompanyDetail topCompany1 = topCompanies.Where(x => x.Company.TopCompany == 1).FirstOrDefault();
   if (topCompany1 == null) return 1;
    CompanyDetail topCompany2 = topCompanies.Where(x => x.Company.TopCompany == 2).FirstOrDefault();
    if (topCompany1 == null) return 2;
    CompanyDetail topCompany3 = topCompanies.Where(x => x.Company.TopCompany == 3).FirstOrDefault();
    if (topCompany1 == null) return 3;

    return -1;
}
```

Quero agora numa *view* Razor chamar este método e colocar o resultado numa variável javascript. Como posso fazer isso?

### Update:

Estou agora a tentar fazer com json, mas não estou a conseguir. Vejam o que tenho na *view*:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/Home/SpotNR',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (result) {

                topSpot = result.Data;

            }

        });
```

e no controller:

```
public JsonResult SpotNR()
{
  int spot = -1;
        IList<CompanyDetail> topCompanies = PresentationServices.Helper.GetCompaniesAll();
        CompanyDetail topCompany1 = topCompanies.Where(x => x.Company.TopCompany == 1).FirstOrDefault();
        if (topCompany1 == null) spot = 1;
        CompanyDetail topCompany2 = topCompanies.Where(x => x.Company.TopCompany == 2).FirstOrDefault();
        if (topCompany1 == null) spot = 2;
        CompanyDetail topCompany3 = topCompanies.Where(x => x.Company.TopCompany == 3).FirstOrDefault();
        if (topCompany1 == null) spot = 3;


    JsonResult returnObj = new JsonResult
    {
        Data = new
        {
            Spot = spot
        }
    };

    return Json(returnObj);
}
```

O problema é que não percebo porque não funciona, mas ele nunca vai ao `success` (topSpot mantém-se undefined) mas a resposta no ChromeDevTools está assim:

```
{"ContentEncoding":null,"ContentType":null,"Data":{"Spot":3},"JsonRequestBehavior":1,"MaxJsonLength":null,"RecursionLimit":null}
```

O número do *spot* está correto, por isso ele processou bem o método.

Comment: No success faça: `topSpot = result.Data.Spot;`

Comment: Ele não chega ao success, vai ao error em vez disso...o que pode estar errado?

Comment: Pede os parâmetros do error (são 3, eu acho) e printa na tela pra ver.

Comment: **parse error**  e **no conversion from text to application/json**

Comment: Coloca `dataType: 'json'` no ajax e testa

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @jbueno ! Assim volta ao success sem problema. Vou ver as diferenças do `application/json` para `json`.

Comment: Ótimo então. Se você quiser, pode ver algo [neste link](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8216)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Views* não fazem chamada de *actions*, pelo menos não diretamente. Me parece que você está tentando resumir um comportamento de aplicação desktop para uma aplicação web.

O que você pode fazer é uma requisição pro servidor e devolver um JSON com o valor retornado da sua função.

Exemplo:

No Controller:

```
public JsonResult GetSpot()
{
    int result = -1; //seu código deve setar o valor de result
    return Json(new { data = result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Na *View*:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetSpot", "Controller")',
    data: data,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
        var variavel = response.data; //Aqui está o retorno do controller
    },
    error: function(){
        // Algo deu errado
    }
});
```